# how to read and write data and accepting connection using socket channel

Tags: java, sockets, nio, channel

I have created a simple server client application using java NIO.
I used a single selector there for accepting connection, reading data and writing.
But I want an application where 1 selector will be busy in accepting the connection while the 2nd selector will read the data and the 3rd selector will write the data.

Means I donot want to put all the load into single selector.

How to achieve this?
Is there any online help

Thanks
Deepak.

// Create the selector
        Selector selector = Selector.open();

```
    // Create two non-blocking server sockets on 80 and 81
    ServerSocketChannel ssChannel1 = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    ssChannel1.configureBlocking(false);
    ssChannel1.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(80));

    // Register both channels with selector
    ssChannel1.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

    while (true) {
        // Wait for an event
        selector.select();

        // Get list of selection keys with pending events
        Iterator it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

        // Process each key
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            // Get the selection key
            SelectionKey selKey = (SelectionKey)it.next();

            // Remove it from the list to indicate that it is being processed
            it.remove();

            // Check if it's a connection request
            if (selKey.isAcceptable()) {
                // Get channel with connection request
                ServerSocketChannel ssChannel = (ServerSocketChannel)selKey.channel();

                // Accepting a Connection on a ServerSocketChannel
                SocketChannel sChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();

    // If serverSocketChannel is non-blocking, sChannel may be null
    if (sChannel == null) {
        // There were no pending connection requests; try again later.
        // To be notified of connection requests,

    } else {
        // Use the socket channel to communicate with the client

    }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I ask why you are attempting this sort of design? What do you expect to gain by it?

Comment: actually it makes my performance low.

Answer (score 7):

Usually, on a non-blocking tcp server, first accept, then read, then write,

you need to register the selector in this order to make sense.

---

### Example code

Here is a full example of non-blocking io:

**TcpChannelTest.java**: (*a **TestNG** testing class*)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

/**
 * tcp channel test
 * 
 * @author eric
 * @date Sep 2, 2012 9:17:40 PM
 */
public class TcpChannelTest {
    public String serverHost = "localhost";
    public int serverPort = 12345;

    private ServerSocketChannel server;
    private int clientSerial = 0;
    private int clientCount = 5;

    // test tcp non-blocking channel,
    @Test
    public void testTcpNonBlockingChanne() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // start server
        startServerNonBlocking();

        Thread.sleep(500); // wait server to be ready, before start client,

        // start clients
        for (int i = 0; i < clientCount; i++) {
            startClientOnce();
        }

        // shutdown server,
        Thread.sleep(500); // wait client to be handled,
        shutdownServer();
    }

    // start non-blocking server,
    private void startServerNonBlocking() throws IOException {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
                    server.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(serverHost, serverPort)); // bind,
                    server.configureBlocking(false); // non-blocking mode,

                    Selector selector = Selector.open();
                    server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

                    while (true) {
                        selector.select();
                        Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();

                        // process each ready key...
                        Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = readyKeys.iterator();
                        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
                            iterator.remove();

                            if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                                SocketChannel client = server.accept();
                                System.out.printf("[%s]:\t%s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), "accept connection");
                                client.configureBlocking(false);

                                // prepare for read,
                                client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                            } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                                // read
                                SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                                ByteBuffer inBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                                while (client.read(inBuf) > 0) {
                                    System.out.printf("[%s]:\t%s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), new String(inBuf.array(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                                }

                                // prepare for write,
                                client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
                            } else if (key.isWritable()) {
                                SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                                String response = "hi - from non-blocking server";
                                byte[] bs = response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bs);
                                client.write(buffer);

                                // switch to read, and disable write,
                                client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, "t-server-threads").start();
    }

    // close server,
    private void shutdownServer() {
        try {
            if (server != null) {
                server.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * tcp client - via channel,
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * It send once request.
     * </p>
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void startClientOnce() throws IOException {
        // start client in a new thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SocketChannel client = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress(serverHost, serverPort));

                    // write
                    String request = "hello - from client [" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "}";
                    byte[] bs = request.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bs);
                    while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                        client.write(buffer);
                    }

                    // read
                    ByteBuffer inBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                    while (client.read(inBuf) > 0) {
                        System.out.printf("[%s]:\t%s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), new String(inBuf.array(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                    }

                    client.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, "t-channelClient-" + clientSerial++).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to register a channel with multiple Selectors using `register(Selector sel, int ops)`. You then register different interest ops on each of the selectors:

```
// After the accepting a connection:
SelectionKey readKey = sChannel.register(readSelector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

// When you have something to write:
SelectionKey writeKey = sChannel.register(writeSelector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
```

Comment: No, because this is usually not the way you do it. I assume you already looked at http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/ to read up on basic NIO handling. You can also look at various NIO implementations. My code at http://naga.googlecode.com is free to copy or use.